# How to format date in partial view MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, date-format

I am currently developing asp.net core(Framework 3.1) application. I am getting date from database and storing it in string(tried using DateTime but didn't work). Here's my code in model:

```
public string TranDate { get; set; }
salesList.Add(new SalesData()
{
TranDate = dt.Rows[i]["TRANDATE"].ToString(),   
});
```

It displays date in "2020/06/06 00:00:00" format.
In partial view:

```
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TranDate)
</td>
```

Now I want to display date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format like "06/06/2020" in my partial view. I have tried many ways like display templates, editor templates, String.Format but nothing works. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like the following;

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); //set a default date
if (DateTime.TryParse(TranDate, out DateTime usersDate))
{
    formattedDate = usersDate.ToShortDateString();
}
TranDate = formattedDate;
```

Some of this may be too much, but the core premise is that using the DateTime.TryParse method ensures that the date being passed into it (your "TranDate" parameter) can even be converted to a date. I know it is coming from the database and likely a Date field itself, but we really should not trust that, to be sure.